# Azure Automation jobs breaking VM-located application REST requests

Tags: azure, xmlhttprequest, virtual-machine, azure-automation, jsessionid

I have an application (VBS) that pulls data from a 3rd party web site via xmlhttp REST requests.

**The first** REST call of this application is to a log-in URL that returns also a JSESSIONID cookie ('*Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=7XYZD; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly*').
The called URL is 'https://www.bullionvault.com/secure/j_security_check?j_username=XXX&j_password=YYY'.

**The second** request, which needs me to be logged-in, pulls actual information from another URL of that web site, returning the data as XML document response as '*.responseXML*'. This flow works just fine if I execute the application while working on the VM (rdp), or also locally from my laptop.

Now, when I use a **Azure Automation** job to trigger the very same application on the VM the second (data) request does not return the expected XML document anymore; I get '*200 OK*' but then the (useless) log-in page of the site as HTTP document as the '*.responseText*'; '*.responseXML*' is empty.

Is seems that using an Azure Automation job is preventing the JSESSIONID from being sent back to the REST server when doing the data request. Hence, the server does not recognize me anymore, and send me back its log-in page. Note that there is no web browser involved explicitely.

Question: **Is my suspicion of using Azure Automation breaking the application true; and how to fix this problem?**

Comment: Please note that  when I trigger the very same application via an Azure Automation Account job there are no cookies like 'Set-Cookie: unitOfWeight=KG; Path=/'  anymore in the response headers of a login request. Subsequent xmlhttp data request fail; instead of the expected data XML I get the html of the log-in page as request responseText. Is seems tha the JSESSIONID cookie was filtered out. Problem seems to be the use of the AAC Service Principal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sandbox kind of setup instead of a hybird worker to execute then as the sandbox is a limited version of the Windows OS and user behavior like cookies and network configuration might not be the same so I would suggest trying out the hybrid worker (which runs under Local System context by default) to see if you can get some better-defined behavior.

Comment: "sandbox"? - the code with the REST call runs on a Win VM. Also, is needs to run via the Automation Account, not local or hybrid - what's the point in testing that? Is this maybe a network / security issue that http/REST traffic is somewhat filtered by if running under an Azure Automation Account Service Principal?